# Make a pattern alternate

Tags: code-challenge, sequence

**Problem**

You are given a sequence of coloured balls (red `R` and green `G`). One such possible sequence is:

```
RGGGRRGGRGRRRGGGRGRRRG
```

In as few moves as possible, you must make it so that each ball is a different colour to its neighbours (i.e. the sequence alternates.)

```
RGRGRGRGRGRGRGRGRGRGRG
```

You should write a program that can convert an unordered sequence (in this case a string) with equal numbers of "R" and "G" into a sequence where the items alternate. One example session is below, for a naive algorithm (`<` is input to program, `>` is output. It isn't necessary to include the carets on the input or output.)

```
< RGGGRRGGRGRRRGGGRGRRRG
> RGGRGRGGRGRRRGGGRGRRRG
> RGRGGRGGRGRRRGGGRGRRRG
> RGRGRGGGRGRRRGGGRGRRRG
> RGRGRGGRGGRRRGGGRGRRRG
> RGRGRGGRGRGRRGGGRGRRRG
> RGRGRGGRGRGRGRGRGGRRRG
> RGRGRGGRGRGRGRGRGRGRRG
> RGRGRGGRGRGRGRGRGRGRGR
> RGRGRGRGGRGRGRGRGRGRGR
> RGRGRGRGRGGRGRGRGRGRGR
> RGRGRGRGRGRGGRGRGRGRGR
> RGRGRGRGRGRGRGGRGRGRGR
> RGRGRGRGRGRGRGRGGRGRGR
> RGRGRGRGRGRGRGRGRGGRGR
> RGRGRGRGRGRGRGRGRGRGGR
> RGRGRGRGRGRGRGRGRGRGRG (15 moves)
```

Another possibility is outputting "5,7" for example to indicate swapping of positions 5 and 7.

You may position *either* Red or Green first, and you don't have to be consistent. Each sequence will be the same length as every other sequence.

You may only swap any two letters in each move (they do not need to be adjacent.)

**Winning Criteria**

The program must show each step of the sort process. The program which makes the fewest *total* moves for all the below strings, wins. If there is a tie, the shortest code will win.

**Input Strings**

The following strings will be used to test the programs:

```
GGGGGGGGGGRRRRRRRRRR
GGRRGGRRGGRRGGRRGGRR
RRGGGGRRRRGGGGRRRRGG
GRRGRGGGGRRRGGGGRRRR
GRGGGRRRRGGGRGRRGGRR
RGRGRGRGRGRGRGRGRGRG
```

The last sequence should result in zero moves.

Comment: Shouldn't "You may only swap any two *pairs* in each move" read "You may only swap any two *letters* in each move"?

Comment: @dude very good, I'll correct that.

Comment: Any requirement that a particular letter start the sorted sequence?

Comment: @dmckee From the question - "You may position either Red or Green first, and you don't have to be consistent."

Comment: Nice problem to work on. I suggest that you ask folks to post several examples of their input and output.  This way, those who don't program in the language chosen can make an evaluation about the suitabiity of the outputs for the respective inputs.

Comment: A little bit more challenging variation is where you have the restriction that you can only swap neighboring elements. So if you have an array you can swap a[i] and a[j] if abs(i - j) == 1

Comment: Can we assume it's possible to do? Eg. `RRR` would be invalid input - or do we have to return a falsy value?

Answer (score 5):

### Python, <strike>140</strike> <strike>122</strike> <strike>119</strike> 115

```
r=raw_input()
f=lambda x:[i for i in range(x,len(r),2)if x-(r[i]!=max('RG',key=r[::2].count))]
print zip(f(0),f(1))
```

Comment: Technically you don't need the assignment of `s`. It'd save you a couple more characters.

Comment: Yeah, you're welcome. I had to do *something* clever after you trounced what I was working on.

Answer (score 3):

### GolfScript (47 chars)

```
:S;4,{S,,{.S=1&3*\1&2*^1$=},\;}%2/{zip}%{,}$0=`
```

E.g. (using a [test case](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OydSUkdHUkdSR1JHUkdSR1JHUkdSRycKOlM7NCx7Uywsey5TPTEmMypcMSYyKl4xJD19LFw7fSUyL3t6aXB9JXssfSQwPWA%3D) which is far easier to check for correctness than any of the suggested ones, which all have lots of correct answers):

```
< RRGGRGRGRGRGRGRGRGRG
> [[1 2]]
```

Output is a list of zero-indexed pairs to swap.

Comment: If [[1 2]] means to swap letters at positions 1 and 2, the result would appear to be identical to the input. Please clarify.

Comment: @dude, what kind of weirdo starts counting at 1?

Comment: (My hand is raised).

Answer (score 3):

### APL 46

```
((2|y)/y←(i≠↑i)/n),[.1](~2|y)/y←(i=↑i)/n←⍳⍴i←⍞
```

Running the given test cases yields:

```
GGGGGGGGGGRRRRRRRRRR
11 13 15 17 19
 2  4  6  8 10
  
GGRRGGRRGGRRGGRRGGRR
3 7 11 15 19
2 6 10 14 18
  
RRGGGGRRRRGGGGRRRRGG
3 5 11 13 19
2 8 10 16 18
  
GRRGRGGGGRRRGGGGRRRR
3 5 11 17 19
4 6  8 14 16
  
GRGGGRRRRGGGRGRRGGRR
7  9 13 15 19
4 10 12 14 18
  
RGRGRGRGRGRGRGRGRGRG
```

The above solution uses index origin 1 with the swaps given in the columns of the results matrix. Two characters can be saved if the input vector i is initialised with the input string prior to execution rather than being input at the time of execution.

Answer (score 2):

### Python, 213 chars

```
I=raw_input()
def M(S,T):
 S=list(S);m=[]
 while S!=list(T):z=zip(S,T);x=z.index(('R','G'));y=z.index(('G','R'));m+=[(x,y)];S[x],S[y]='GR'
 return m
N=len(I)/2
x=M(I,N*'RG')
y=M(I,N*'GR')
print[x,y][len(x)>len(y)]
```

`M` finds the moves required to convert `S` to `T`.  It does this by repeatedly finding an `R` and a `G` out of position and swapping them.  We then find the shorter move sequence to get to either `RGRG...RG` or `GRGR...GR`.

Should find an optimal sequence of moves for every input.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica 238

**Code**

```
f[x_] := With[{g = "GRGRGRGRGRGRGRGRGRGR", c = Characters, p = Position},
y = c[x]; s = c[g]; {v = Equal @@@ ({s, y}\[Transpose]), 
w = Not /@ v}; {vv = Thread[{y, v}], ww = Thread[{y, w}]};
((Flatten /@ {p[#, {"R", False}], p[#, {"G", False}]}) &[If[Count[Equal @@@ 
({s, y}\[Transpose]), False] < 10, vv, ww]])\[Transpose]]
```

N.B.: `\[Transpose]` is a single character, a superscripted "t", in *Mathematica*]

**Examples**

```
f@"GGGGGGGGGGRRRRRRRRRR"
f@"GGRRGGRRGGRRGGRRGGRR"
f@"RRGGGGRRRRGGGGRRRRGG"
f@"GRRGRGGGGRRRGGGGRRRR"
f@"GRGGGRRRRGGGRGRRGGRR"
f@"RGRGRGRGRGRGRGRGRGRG"
f@"GRGRGRGRGRGRGRGRGRGR"
```

> {{12, 1}, {14, 3}, {16, 5}, {18, 7}, {20, 9}}
> {{4, 1}, {8, 5}, {12, 9}, {16, 13}, {20, 17}}
> {{2, 3}, {8, 5}, {10, 11}, {16, 13}, {18, 19}}
> {{2, 1}, {10, 7}, {12, 9}, {18, 13}, {20, 15}}
> {{2, 1}, {6, 3}, {8, 5}, {16, 11}, {20, 17}}
> {}
> {}

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica 134 or 124

Depending on how you count "Transpose[]" which on Mathematica is just one char (no representation here). Spaces added for clarity

```
G = 0; R = 1; 
x_~ d ~ y__:= Transpose[Position[Symbol /@ Characters@x - PadLeft[{}, 20, {y}], #, 1] &
                                                                                 /@ {1, -1}]
f = SortBy[{d[#, 0, 1], d[#, 1, 0]}, Length][[1]] &
```

Sample:

```
f@"GGGGGGGGGGRRRRRRRRRR"
f@"GGRRGGRRGGRRGGRRGGRR"
f@"RRGGGGRRRRGGGGRRRRGG"
f@"GRRGRGGGGRRRGGGGRRRR"
f@"GRGGGRRRRGGGRGRRGGRR"
f@"RGRGRGRGRGRGRGRGRGRG"
f@"GRGRGRGRGRGRGRGRGRGR"
```

Output

```
{{{11}, {2}}, {{13}, {4}}, {{15},  {6}}, {{17},  {8}}, {{19}, {10}}}
{{{3},  {2}}, {{7},  {6}}, {{11}, {10}}, {{15}, {14}}, {{19}, {18}}}
{{{1},  {4}}, {{7},  {6}}, {{9},  {12}}, {{15}, {14}}, {{17}, {20}}}
{{{2},  {1}}, {{10}, {7}}, {{12},  {9}}, {{18}, {13}}, {{20}, {15}}}
{{{2},  {1}}, {{6},  {3}}, {{8},   {5}}, {{16}, {11}}, {{20}, {17}}}
{}
{}
```

Comment: Very economical coding. Nice use of pure functions.

Comment: @dude Thanks :). I'm sure the `PadLeft[{}, 20, {y}], #, 1]` can be compressed a bit more

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript - 173 characters

```
a=prompt(w=[[],[]]).split('');for(i=a.length,f=a[0];i--;)if(i%2<1&&a[i]!=f)w[0].push(i);else if(i%2>0&&a[i]==f)w[1].push(i);for(i=w[0].length;i--;)alert(w[0][i]+','+w[1][i])
```

A great challenge, kept me busy for some time.
Here the codes results for the test cases:

```
GGGGGGGGGGRRRRRRRRRR: [10, 1] [12, 3] [14, 5] [16, 7] [18, 9]
GGRRGGRRGGRRGGRRGGRR: [ 2, 1] [ 6, 5] [10, 9] [14,13] [18,17]
RRGGGGRRRRGGGGRRRRGG: [ 2, 1] [ 4, 7] [10, 9] [12,15] [18,17]
GRRGRGGGGRRRGGGGRRRR: [ 2, 3] [ 4, 5] [10, 7] [16,13] [18,15]
GRGGGRRRRGGGRGRRGGRR: [ 6, 3] [ 8, 9] [12,11] [14,13] [18,17]
RGRGRGRGRGRGRGRGRGRG:
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP - 34 moves - 193 characters

```
$l=strlen($a=$_GET["a"]);$n=$a[0]=="R"?"G":"R";while($i<$l){if($a[++$i]!=$n){echo$o."
";$o=$a=substr($a,0,$i).$n.preg_replace("/".$n."/",$n=="R"?"G":"R",substr($a,$i+1),1);}$n=$n=="R"?"G":"R";}
```

Might still try to improve this...

```
red_green.php?a=GGGGGGGGGGRRRRRRRRRR

GRGGGGGGGGGRRRRRRRRR
GRGRGGGGGGGGRRRRRRRR
GRGRGRGGGGGGGRRRRRRR
GRGRGRGRGGGGGGRRRRRR
GRGRGRGRGRGGGGGRRRRR
GRGRGRGRGRGRGGGGRRRR
GRGRGRGRGRGRGRGGGRRR
GRGRGRGRGRGRGRGRGGRR
GRGRGRGRGRGRGRGRGRGR
```

Comment: it could be better to use `$argv[0]` instead, saving you 2 bytes/each. And will be more valid, since `$argv` is often used for input via CMD